# Django How to Store HTML files in Amazon S3

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I have a question regarding HTML files and Django.  Can the django views file serve html files that are not stored locally and stored on amazon s3?

For example instead of:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

have something like:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.html')
```

Obviously its currently appending the url link to the folder it things html are served from.

Is this sort of thing even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is feasible. Web servers exists just for this reason: **to serve HTML pages to clients**. [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) exists for file storage, such as images, videos, js files, css files, fonts etc. Not HTML!

On the other hand, suppose this was feasible, your Web server should make a `GET` `request` to the HTML stored in S3 (to get the html), then fill it with context variables and then send it to the client (`response`).

The job of a [Django view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) is to `take a Web request and return a Web response`. Not making another `GET` request to get the html which will send as a `respose` right away (!).

Hope that clarifies your question!

Comment: amazon might not agree however: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: A lot of people doens't agree with this. A static web hosting is the best performance we can reach.